# Simple Applications of Differentiation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was practicing on how to answer some couple of minimum-maximum problems in calculus. I stumbled upon this question. The problem looks like this:

"Find two positive numbers whose product is 64, and whose sum is a minimum."

I know that those positive numbers talked by that problem are 8 and 8, after some trial and error. How do you answer it?

Comment: $$(a+b)/2\ge\sqrt{ab}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would start of by letting $x$ and $y$ be the two numbers of interest. We are given that
$$xy = 64$$
and we are looking for when
$$x+y$$
is a minimum. From our constraint we also know that $y = \frac{64}{x}$ and therefore we are looking for the minimum of the function
$$f(x) = x + \frac{64}{x}$$
Differentiating and setting this function equal to $0$ will give us a critical number and then we simply check to see if it is a minimum using the first derivative test.